# How to compare two Date and Time and get Day,Month,hour,min in Android?

Tags: android, date, android-date

I Have this type of Date in String Format 01-18-2013 06:43:35 Now, i want to compare this Date with Current Date and Time and get Day, Month, Hour, Min, .. I Searched this [link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) but didn't get any Solution...Please share some solution..Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This might help,
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

You can parse the Date from string using

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
myDate = df.parse(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question, you would like to Compare a `Date` object with the current date..

Let's say that 'date' is the `Date` object you want to compare with the current date:
Why don't you just do something like `date.after(new Date())`  or `date.before(new Date())` as suggested form the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can get UTC with

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("01-18-2013 06:43:35").getTime();
```

Then compare the result with

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

this may helps you to calculate to diffrent date time in millisecond

```
try{
            Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calDb = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar matchd = Calendar.getInstance();

            mYear = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            mendYear = calDb.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mendMonth = calDb.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mendDay = calDb.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);    
                       // Here you can change day values        
                    calDb.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay-1);

            strbeforedate = mDateFormat.format(calDb.getTime());
            curentdate = mDateFormat.format(calender.getTime());

            calDb.setTime(mDateFormat.parse(strbeforedate));
            calender.setTime(mDateFormat.parse(curentdate));



            String mydate = "2013.03.14 03:11";
            String mdatetime = "";

            deletepath =  new ArrayList<String>();          
            for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){

                try{
                    // here your matching goes and pass date here 

                     matchd.setTime(mDateFormat.parse(mdatetime));
                     long diff = calDb.getTimeInMillis() - calender.getTimeInMillis();
                     long matchdiff = matchd.getTimeInMillis() - calender.getTimeInMillis();
                        if(diff < matchdiff){

                                     // do your work here
                        }else{

                         // do your else work here

                        }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```